# Bootstrap positioning incorrect on mobile devices

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have implemented the following bootstrap layout:

```
<div>
   <div class="row">
      <!-- ********** Images **********-->
      <div class="col-sm">
         <div class="row">
            Image 1
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
         <div class="row">
            Image 2
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-sm">
         <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="position-absolute mr-1"></div>
               <div class="position-absolute mt-1">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 display-23">
               Image 1 - Measurement 1
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="position-absolute mr-1"></div>
               <div class="position-absolute mt-1">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 display-23">
               Image 1 - Measurement 2
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="position-absolute mr-1"></div>
               <div class="position-absolute mt-1">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 display-23">
               Image 1 - Measurement 3
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm">
         <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="position-absolute mr-1"></div>
               <div class="position-absolute mt-1">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 display-23">
               Image 2 - Measurement 1
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="position-absolute mr-1"></div>
               <div class="position-absolute mt-1">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 display-23">
               Image 2 - Measurement 2
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Codeply Link](https://www.codeply.com/p/rEzsL99Hgq)

The layout looks like this on desktop: [Desktop Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JzWl.png)

If you switch to the mobile view, it looks like this: [Mobile view current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZTzT.png)

However, I would like the positioning on mobile devices to look like this: [Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO9VN.png)

Can anyone help me and tell me what I need to do to change the positioning so that it looks like the last layout example?

Comment: There are many more Rows and Columns than you would actually need and I would be certain it is making life harder for you.

Comment: @CuteyfromCuteCode Agree, I have too many rows and columns around the images. Will clean up my code accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved your problem in your existing layout. you can improve layout as its not clean.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>

    <div class="row">
       
      
       <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="row">
               Image 1
            </div>
         </div>
         </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
             <div class="col-2">
                <div class="position-absolute mr-1"></div>
                <div class="position-absolute mt-1">1</div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-10 display-23">
                Image 1 - Measurement 1
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
             <div class="col-2">
                <div class="position-absolute mr-1"></div>
                <div class="position-absolute mt-1">2</div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-10 display-23">
                Image 1 - Measurement 2
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
             <div class="col-2">
                <div class="position-absolute mr-1"></div>
                <div class="position-absolute mt-1">3</div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-10 display-23">
                Image 1 - Measurement 3
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
 
       <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="row">
                   Image 2
                </div>
             </div>
             </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
             <div class="col-2">
                <div class="position-absolute mr-1"></div>
                <div class="position-absolute mt-1">1</div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-10 display-23">
                Image 2 - Measurement 1
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
             <div class="col-2">
                <div class="position-absolute mr-1"></div>
                <div class="position-absolute mt-1">2</div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-10 display-23">
                Image 2 - Measurement 2
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! This has already helped me a lot. The only problem your code causes is that the points below the "images" (1 - Image 1 - Measurement 1 and 1 - Image 2 - Measurement 1 and so on) are not in a row as soon as the images have different heights. Is there any way to fix this?